# How to match two tables id laravel

Tags: laravel-5

```
@foreach($SearchResult as $fri => $friends)
{{ $confriend[$fri]->friend_one }}
{{ $confriend[$fri]->friend_two }}
@endforeach
```

`$friends` has searched friend list and `$confriend[$fri]->friend_one` and `$confriend[$fri]->friend_two` are the record which are already friends with logged-in user, so I want to match those ids with each other so I can show the user that they are your friends.